# Why does a Mongoid Array field contain hashes (["$each"=>"My value"]?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have an `Array` field in my Mongoid model. I am then pushing a few elements to this array.

Do anyone know why my Array elements gets wrapped in hashes, all with the key `"$each"`?

```
class Website
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :visits, type: Array
end

website = Website.create
website.push(visits: Time.zone.now)
website.push(visits: Time.zone.now)

puts website.visits.inspect # => [{"$each"=>[2014-04-01 16:32:43 UTC]}, {"$each"=>[2014-04-01 16:32:43 UTC]}]
```

Comment: Why `website.push` instead of `website.visits.push`?

Comment: Becuase of the documentation [here](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#push). But your solution does fix my issue. Only downside is that I have to call `website.save` after the push. Any idea if this can be avoided?

Comment: Those docs are for Mongoid2, you're using Mongoid4. Maybe you should look at more recent docs: http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/frames

Comment: Ah, right you are. Thanks. Feel free to put your answer in, then I will approve it.

Comment: I don't know Mongoid4 that well (still using 3), feel free to answer your own question.